# Use label array as colormap for one vector scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to scatter my data without specifying the x argument in scatter. In other words scatter the data and ignore x
For example:

```py
data = [83, 67, 90,  6, 93, 41, 70, 84, 39, 94]
labels = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
pyplot.scatter(labels, data, c=labels)
```

This gives the following figure:
[image]

I want to ignore labels as the x_axis

I could do this and get the result I want:
`pyplot.scatter(numpy.zeros(len(data)), data, c=labels)`
[image]

But I don't want to specify the x_axis

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just edited the question. hope it's clearer now

Comment: Stay with a scatter. It's not really clear what "without x_axis" means, but of course you can hide it, or set any custom labels. I would suggest you provide a [mcve] (no need for Kmeans or anything, but it should be runnable by itself) where you use scatter, show the output and tell us what you don't like about it.

Comment: just edited the question with what you asked !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the part "without a x-axis". Is this what you are looking for?

```
sns.stripplot(y=data, x=labels, palette=['red','blue'])
```

[image]

I suppose that's what you are trying to get?

```
data = [83, 67, 90,  6, 93, 41, 70, 84, 39, 94]
labels = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
sns.stripplot(y=data, x=np.zeros(len(data)), hue=labels)
```

[image]

Comment: how come you don't have data vertically straight? since labels has 2 values only